# Passing references to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overloading, private

I'm having an issue with a private recursive helper function which I am passing a reference in a pointer to. I am getting an error that says

"No instance of overloaded function "insertSymbol" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (String, Expression *)"

I think I'm misunderstanding something about passing references. Can somebody help me out?

```
struct ExpressionTree {
    private:
        Expression* root;

        bool insertSymbol(String& symbol, Expression*& root) {
            if (root == nullptr) { // base case
                root = new Expression(symbol);
                return true;
            }

            if ((*(*root).getSymbol()).c_str()[0] == '~') { 
                return insertSymbol(symbol, (*root).getLeftChild()); // Error occurs here
            }
        }

    public:
        ExpressionTree(void) {
            root = 0x00;
        }

        // returns true if insert was successful, otherwise returns false
        bool insertSymbol(String& symbol) {
            if (symbol.size == 0) return false;
            return insertSymbol(symbol, root); // Calls recursive helper function
        }
};
```

Comment: We can't tell what `getLeftChild` is or what it returns. But it looks like you're trying to bind a reference to a temporary, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a reference to a temporary. One possible fix would be this:

```
bool insertSymbol(String& symbol, Expression*& root) {
    if (root == nullptr) { // base case
        root = new Expression(symbol);
        return true;
    }
    return insertSymbolHelper(symbol, root);
}

bool insertSymbolHelper(String& symbol, Expression* root) {
    if ((*(*root).getSymbol()).c_str()[0] == '~') { 
        return insertSymbolHelper(symbol, (*root).getLeftChild()); // Error occurs here
    }
    // rest of code goes here
}
```

Comment: While I haven't seen enough code to be sure, I would bet this fix will result in an invalid pointer dereference the second time `insertSymbol` is called.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm assuming `getLeftChild` cannot return NULL. If it can, then more changes are needed. (Perhaps `getLeftChild` should return a reference?)